# custom post type template

Tags: custom-post-types

I am following the wp doc for adding a custom post type:

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'startup',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Startup' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Startup' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

I have made single-startup.php in themes root but it doesn't load for any post with that type.

For example if I go to test.com/startup/my-page This will show index.php contents.

I know there are several questions like this, but none of them worked for me. I don't know why.

[image]

I have random string in single-startup.php

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod...

When I visit custom post page: 'abc.com/startup/some-startup-page/' I see same content as 'abc.com/' i.e index page.

However when I visit a default type post/page i.e 'abc.com/test-post/' It works perfectly. single-post.php and page.php are loaded correctly.

Its just single-startup.php that is causing problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say that you get the "index.php" contents, do you mean that you're seeing the index.php template, but the correct post is loaded within the loop? Or you're seeing the index.php template loaded with some other content?

Comment: when I visit the permalink echoed by a startup post type like 'abc.com/startup/some-startup-page/' I see same content as 'abc.com/' i.e index page

Comment: please check the updated question, ty

Comment: Are you actually redirected or does the URL stay the same?

Comment: No redirections. I have attached more snapshots.

Comment: Ok, I noticed something. Even though I have visited startup url several times. Its still blue. It should be purple like other url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be completely off the mark, but have you tried regenerating your .htaccess file, after creating the new post type.

This usually results in some awkward behaviour.

To do this, simply go to settings->permalinks and hit "save".

In terms of the template structure, everything does seem fine.

Comment: I didn't even have to hit save button. Only going to permalink page made it work.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)